# How to add agent to lotus client using java

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I wrote a simple agent program to get the count of unprocessedDocuments() and updateprocessedDoc.

```
 public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

public void NotesMain() {
    FileWriter fw = null;
    try {
        Session session = getSession();
        AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
        DocumentCollection dc = agentContext.getUnprocessedDocuments();
        Document doc = dc.getFirstDocument();
        System.out.println(dc.getCount());
        while(doc!= null){
            agentContext.updateProcessedDoc(doc);
            doc = dc.getNextDocument();
            }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I wrote this agent program in the lotus notes client and it is working fine. Now I want to add this agent to other lotus machine programatically.

I have a code to list all the agents in the lotus notes client and if my agent is not there, then I need to add this agent into their machine. This code runs externally, not inside lotus client. That is the solution should not extend AgentBase, it will extend NOtesThread.

Kindly suggest me, how to achieve this. 
Assume that adding this agent without involving administrator.

Comment: What is your reason for not involving the administrator? I can't think of a way, but on principle I'd say that nobody should be allowed to add code to the user client's without administrator involvement. The admnistrator is responsible for maintaining the security of the Lotus Notes environment.

Comment: You are confusing me. Domino Agents are written in Databases, not directly on a client. What database did you write this agent in? Perhaps the users mail DB? Perhaps the users local names.nsf? Perhaps somewhere else. Depending on where it was written there are different approaches to getting the code distributed to other users.

Comment: This agent is written in mail database of the user.

Comment: This is required to test our codes in different machines. It is kind of a Proof of Concept. There are two approaches, either go to each users and manually add the agent into their database or programatically add the agents into the users machine. In either case it is done with the user's approval. For this small PoC we don't want to involve administrator.

Comment: Add this agent to the mail database template and use this template to refresh design for users' mail databases.

Answer (score 0):

You have indicated that the agent has been included in a mail template.

The proper procedure for this should be:

- With the administrator's help and authorization, create a new copy of the mail template including the new agent.
- Ask the administrator to replace the design of the first tester's email with the new template.
- Test.
- After the test is completed, ask the administrator to replace the design for the mail database for the additional testers.
- Ideally this should be performed in a separate test domain, to avoid having consequences (e.g. massive delivery of emails) affecting the production domain.

Given that the administrator is responsible for the environment in which you are performing these tests, not including him seems, at the very least, disrespectful, and in any case, unprofessional.